# Flex URLLoader Upload - Determinate Progress Bar?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, upload, filereference

My application asks the user to select files for upload using a FileReference / FileReferenceList. The client then compresses the File data and uses URLLoader to upload the contents of the file.

One problem with the URLLoader is that the progress event does not get triggered for uploads. How do I track the upload progress? I am unable to create a FileReference for the newly compressed ZIP ByteArray.

-- Sri

Comment: this sounds like two separate questions... the first is about the progress indicator, the second is about getting a FileReference for the file you yourself generate.

Comment: Not only, the only reason I may need a FileReference is to track the progress. I believe generating a FileReference is not possible as the data property is read only.

Comment: I have never been able to get progress for file upload.  What I have done in the past is used the async read method (I can look it up for you if you can't find it) and upload the file in small chunks (256k or so) which will give you a steady feedback of how far you've gone. You won't know how far along you are within your individual file slices, but if they're small enough, it really doesn't matter.  On the server just read the binary data and tack it to the end of the total file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the situation of Flex / Flash APIs, the answer is "not possible"